# 4 slices of bytearray to compare using multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading, arraylist, parallel-processing, arrays

i am stuck with this Second stage of a project:
splitting A byte[] to 4 slices( to load a QuadCore I5 CPU) then with each slice,  start a thread (comparison task) on each core.

the cause is trying to accellerate a comparison between two of same size bytearrays
how do i thread this ?

```
    [DllImport("msvcrt.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    static extern int memcmp(byte[] b1, byte[] b2, long count);




class ArrayView<T> : IEnumerable<T> 
    {
        private readonly T[] array;
        private readonly int offset, count;
        public ArrayView(T[] array, int offset, int count)
        {
            this.array = array; this.offset = offset; this.count = count;
        }
        public int Length { get { return count; } }
        public T this[int index] {
            get { if (index < 0 || index >= this.count)
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
            else
                return this.array[offset + index]; }
            set { if (index < 0 || index >= this.count)
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
            else
                this.array[offset + index] = value; }
        }
        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            for (int i = offset; i < offset + count; i++)
                yield return array[i];
        } 
        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            IEnumerator<T> enumerator = this.GetEnumerator();
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                yield return enumerator.Current;
            }
        }
    } 




    public void CopmarArrSlice()
    {

    byte[] LoadedArr = File.ReadAllBytes("testFileCompare2Scr.bmp");

    int LoddArLn = OrgArr.Length;
    int range =  (LoddArLn / 4) - LoddAremainder;
    int divisionremain = LoddArLn - (range * 4);

    ArrayView<byte> LddP1 = new ArrayView<byte>(OrgArr, 0, range);
    ArrayView<byte> LddP2 = new ArrayView<byte>(OrgArr, p1.Length, range);
    ArrayView<byte> LddP3 = new ArrayView<byte>(OrgArr, (p1.Length + p2.Length), range);
    ArrayView<byte> LddP4 = new ArrayView<byte>(OrgArr, (p1.Length + p2.Length + p3.Length), range + divisionremain);


        if (AreEqual(LddP1, CapturedP1)) ....Do Somthing

    }


    public bool AreEqual(byte[] a, byte[] b)
    {
        if (a == b)
           return true;
        if (a == null || b == null)
            return false;
        if (a.Length != b.Length)
            return false;
        return memcmp(a, b, a.Length) == 0;
    }


    CopmarArrSlice();
```

in this case how is it possibole with the AreEqual(using memcmp) to compare it with using 4 threads/Parallelism  , to compute on each CpuCore

Comment: I fully expect multi-threading to make this task slower

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a function that takes advantage of multiple cores when possible but it seems to suffer a serious performance hit from the p/invoke calls. I'm thinking this version would only make sense when testing very large arrays.

```
static unsafe class NativeParallel
{
    [DllImport("msvcrt.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    static extern int memcmp(byte* b1, byte* b2, int count);

    public static bool AreEqual(byte[] a, byte[] b)
    {
        // The obvious optimizations
        if (a == b)
            return true;
        if (a == null || b == null)
            return false;
        if (a.Length != b.Length)
            return false;

        int quarter = a.Length / 4;
        int r0 = 0, r1 = 0, r2 = 0, r3 = 0;
        Parallel.Invoke(
            () =>  {
                fixed (byte* ap = &a[0])
                fixed (byte* bp = &b[0])
                    r0 = memcmp(ap, bp, quarter);                        
            },
            () => {
                fixed (byte* ap = &a[quarter])
                fixed (byte* bp = &b[quarter])
                    r1 = memcmp(ap, bp, quarter);
            },
            () => {
                fixed (byte* ap = &a[quarter * 2])
                fixed (byte* bp = &b[quarter * 2])
                    r2 = memcmp(ap, bp, quarter);
            },
            () => {
                fixed (byte* ap = &a[quarter * 3])
                fixed (byte* bp = &b[quarter * 3])
                    r3 = memcmp(ap, bp, a.Length - (quarter * 3));
            }
        );
        return r0 + r1 + r2 + r3 == 0;
    }
}
```

For the most part it is actually slower than an optimized safe version.

```
static class SafeParallel
{
    public static bool AreEqual(byte[] a, byte[] b)
    {
        if (a == b)
            return true;
        if (a == null || b == null)
            return false;
        if (a.Length != b.Length)
            return false;

        bool b1 = false;
        bool b2 = false;
        bool b3 = false;
        bool b4 = false;
        int quarter = a.Length / 4;
        Parallel.Invoke(
            () => b1 = AreEqual(a, b, 0, quarter),
            () => b2 = AreEqual(a, b, quarter, quarter),
            () => b3 = AreEqual(a, b, quarter * 2, quarter),
            () => b4 = AreEqual(a, b, quarter * 3, a.Length)
        );
        return b1 && b2 && b3 && b4;
    }

    static bool AreEqual(byte[] a, byte[] b, int start, int length)
    {
        var len = length / 8;
        if (len > 0)
        {
            for (int i = start; i < len; i += 8)
            {
                if (BitConverter.ToInt64(a, i) != BitConverter.ToInt64(b, i))
                    return false;
            }
        }
        var remainder = length % 8;
        if (remainder > 0)
        {
            for (int i = length - remainder; i < length; i++)
            {
                if (a[i] != b[i])
                    return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: just so you know i have named a class of byteArray Comparison after you ChaosBAcomp (: form last post, gonna Benchmark them both now , thanks again

Comment: ok copied the code (first) to my project , there are few errors 1):---Error 6 The best overloaded method match for 'MyScrCaptu_Comp.MyForm1.memcmp(byte[], byte[], long)' ...MyForm1.cs 246 22 MyScrCaptu_Comp ....(#2)Error 5 `Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelOptions` because it is not a delegate type 243 13 ...(#3)...Error 8 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'byte*' to 'byte[]' 246 33

Comment: @LoneXcoder - I think you need to switch the signature for `memcmp` to `static extern int memcmp(byte* b1, byte* b2, int count);
`.

Comment: sorry didn't copy yours cause i did have one (:
gonna give it a try

Comment: .ok last time it was native(pinvoke memcmp) but safe , not parrallel , and now its unsafe & parrallel , gonna Chek , benchmarking... please don't hold your breath ; it will take me some.. 20 - 40 minutes to go through them again . come back.. i will post results.

Comment: @LoneXcoder - Add `unsafe` to the signature for `memcmp`. `static unsafe extern int memcmp(byte* b1, byte* b2, int count);`

Comment: funny i think i did and still didn't work did it again now it does so i start benchmarks in few minutes . Thanks alot So far

Comment: still working on the setup not orgenized as you with the Custum Func<> thing , and your tests differ cause i did it with bytearry from file you did it by inventing one randomly(: so i need to make some uniforming ... some more time , please do follow if you have the time i gonna make it soon , thanks man !

Comment: i just finished checking on a small Array (W200xH100) 60K length. but i think something's wrong with parrallell at all.
had look at the benchmark then thougt... how can it be that parlllel costs 300% of single therad. @ChaosPandion, could you split Data into 4 parts and load each to its thread ? so any false breaks computing. thats for Parallel vs single thread-small data, the rest of results (safe unsafe nativeUnsafe) they're very close:still, my favorite Native is the leader (by min 10%  Max 20% vs Not-using pinvoke) that's so far for small data gonna run again on 1000x800 pixels this time

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't have to split your bytes, in a single thread & classic c# way you would use

```
foreach(byte currentArr in LoadedArr)
{
    if (AreEqyal(currentArr, CapturedP1))
           ....Do Somthing
}
```

But to treat every single byte by distributing the workload to multiple threads, you have to use the following syntax;

```
// max your threads count in my case 16,
int[] sums = new int[16];// optional, just to know the workload
public void ProcessMyByte(byte current)
{
    if (AreEqyal(current, CapturedP1))
           ....Do Somthing

       // optional just to know what thread is in
        sums[Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId]++;// increment the number of iterations done by the thread who did this elementary process
}

.... Main()...
{
....

byte[] LoadedArr = File.ReadAllBytes("testFileCompare2Scr.bmp");
Parallel.ForEach(LoadedArr, ProcessMyByte);

...
}
```

so the parallelism will be managed on your behalf and its even better because when a thread is idle it gets the next task, not as if you split it into 4 every thread have to process Length/4.

Comment: i am not loosing time on splitting the arrays, the images are stored as Byte[] in one folder, then i load all byte[] into memory split them to slices then dump the original arrays and use only part of data to do comparison, i think if i compare only 2|3 out of the 4 slices i will still have a false if they're really not same. do you still think not splitting i don't understand the code (first one) you posted and how is it un necessery - slices  comparison, slice to slice vs the full array against full arrays unless u know what you're saying and there's a problem with my knowlage understanding

Comment: goanna look in to this... so what my `ProcessMyByte()` do is compute the equality, and then **No matter** true || false it "increments the therad" <- written in english letters but sound like Literary Chinese to me ( i like that info-`Parallel.ForEach()` too , so can you open it a little either by referencing where(&under what search term) to look for it, or if you really have the patience to describe it deeper by one step , thanks for your help Séddik !

Comment: take a look at this link http://books.google.com/books?id=rgloOPCa3zoC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA763#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: sorry for the bad english, I was in hurry, *not increment the thread* but counts the **number of its iterations**, for example i've tried do a `parallel.foreach` with byte[] with a length of 20, the thread number 2 did 6 operations, the N°9 did 13 and the N° 11 did the rest.

Comment: that's a great book, it covers almost all

Comment: didn't implement it yet in my code but i learn on paralel.for/foreach and ConcurrentQueue